# Katalon - IE won't perform click

Tags: internet-explorer, katalon-studio

I have problem with my test script in Katalon for IE. There is `click` operation which works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it won't perform `click` in IE and Katalon returns `Pass` result for this step. Did someone meet this problem before?
I have tried wait for element:

```
WebUI.waitForElementVisible(findTestObject('Commity - SG/LOG IN page/LOG IN - button'), 0)
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Commity - SG/LOG IN page/LOG IN - button'))
```

but it didn't helped.

Comment: Which IE version you are using? I suppose you are using IE11 under Windows 10, so I think you should make sure this setting is done from your side: 
For Windows 10, you also need to set "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100% in display settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Vinh Nguyen, I had wrong scaling on my system (125%). I've set it to 100% and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

See http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/challenges-to-run-selenium-scripts-with-ie-browser/

I think your problem will be solved with these solutions

Comment: I've tried all options from suggested website, but it still don't work. Any other suggestions? Script works fine with chrome, firefox, but not with IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

**As i answered, solution was in link:**

[image: wrong browser zoom level ie]